# how to create curl function same as like wp_remote_post in core php

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, php-curl

I want to create in curl function which will give me same response as Wordpress **wp_remote_post** I am working with core php

```
function curlPost($url, $data=null, $header=null) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    if(!empty($header)){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    if(!empty($header)){
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

I am using this simple function, and not able to get response as **wp_remote_post**
I want to create same function which will get the input and produce result same as wp_remote_post. I am new to Wordpress and don't know this this function is written.

Comment: If you are using the same function, and it does not work the same way, what have you tried to resolve the problem? What **exactly** is not working?

Comment: You can browse the code... Start here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-includes/http.php#L177